Convert bigquery external table into normal table
Hey I have a really simple workflow, I'm connecting a google sheets to bigquery with the google drive source, the query is created and is working. But now I want to have this external table turn into a bigquery normal table (or native table) and the new table synced with the external sources? So the new rows in the google sheet can be added as well.
How can I accomplish this?
I'm new in big query so I don't know how to get it done

You can do the following:
CREATE TABLE <native_table_reference> AS
SELECT * FROM <external_table_reference>

